# Writing to /Users/ahmed.d.hamdallah/.config/psysh/psysh_history is not allowed

Tags: laravel-5, tinker

I have a macbookpro 2017, and i face a problems when use php artisan tinker. Here's a screenshot of what I got:

```
[![ErrorException  : Writing to /Users/ahmed.d.hamdallah/.config/psysh/psysh_history is not allowed.

  at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/vendor/psy/psysh/src/ConfigPaths.php:215
    211|             if (\is_writable($file)) {
    212|                 return $file;
    213|             }
    214| 
  > 215|             \trigger_error(\sprintf('Writing to %s is not allowed.', $file), E_USER_NOTICE);
    216| 
    217|             return false;
    218|         }
    219| 

  Exception trace:

  1   trigger_error("Writing to /Users/ahmed.d.hamdallah/.config/psysh/psysh_history is not allowed.")
      /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/vendor/psy/psysh/src/ConfigPaths.php:215

  2   Psy\ConfigPaths::touchFileWithMkdir("/Users/ahmed.d.hamdallah/.config/psysh/psysh_history")
      /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Configuration.php:376

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.][1]][1]


[![ErrorException  : Writing to /Users/ahmed.d.hamdallah/.config/psysh/psysh_history is not allowed.

  at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/vendor/psy/psysh/src/ConfigPaths.php:215
    211|             if (\is_writable($file)) {
    212|                 return $file;
    213|             }
    214| 
  > 215|             \trigger_error(\sprintf('Writing to %s is not allowed.', $file), E_USER_NOTICE);
    216| 
    217|             return false;
    218|         }
    219| 

  Exception trace:

  1   trigger_error("Writing to /Users/ahmed.d.hamdallah/.config/psysh/psysh_history is not allowed.")
      /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/vendor/psy/psysh/src/ConfigPaths.php:215

  2   Psy\ConfigPaths::touchFileWithMkdir("/Users/ahmed.d.hamdallah/.config/psysh/psysh_history")
      /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Configuration.php:376

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.][2]][2]
```

Comment: You need to write more on this... What is your question ? What were you tring to do ?

Comment: hello dears,
i wanna use the tinker but it gives me this exception so any one can help?

Comment: Hello! No images of text please. Copy paste the text in the question and explain what you are doing

Comment: It's an option bro